# What would be an ideal caching system for a PHP Heroku App?

Tags: php, caching, heroku, amazon-s3

I am working to improve the server time for a PHP App on Heroku. I noticed that when I cache a PHP file to a HTML file, my service times go down from 2500+ms to around 20ms.

Now, here are a couple of problems at hand...

1) The cached HTML page would need to change after certain user actions. Now a deluge of such actions could easily drown the server. The actions can come in deluge, or there could be no action for hours.

2) The app would typically run on multiple dyno's on Heroku, each with its own ephemeral file system. So each dyno can potentially have its own version of cached file, and the cached file will disappear automatically after 24 hours, or every time I push some new code to the server.

I am new to the world of web programming, and thinking of solving the above in the following way. Are there better ways to do it ? Any tools ? plugins ? frameworks ? Please do suggest. They have to work on Heroku though.

1. Store the cached file on S3. So most of my site would then run from S3. In case of a user action, the cache will be updated.
2. Instead of updating the cache directly, I will schedule the update to happen after 30s. A file by the name of cachedpage.html.scheduled will be placed on S3 for this time period. Any requests that come during this time period will be invalidated.

I am assuming that a redirect to S3 would be much cheaper than DB Queries. Can there be a problem with S3 when the traffic becomes heavy ?

Looking forward to your feedback.

Thanks
Manish

Comment: you could use a separate memcached server shared by all of the instances.

Comment: that means I should just cache my db queries and not the whole page and store the objects in memcache ?

Comment: or cache pre-rendered page fragments.